# Compilation error. Line 11: Could not find function or function reference 'crossover'

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to fix the code below. I'm doing it to backtest a trading strategy. My level = total noob
`

```
//@version=5
// This script takes a position each time the 8-period EMA on a 30-minute timeframe
// crosses the 47-period SMA on the same timeframe.
// Take profit is 3 dollars from the position and stop loss is 1 dollar from the position.

// Set up variables for the moving averages
ema8 = ta.ema(close, 8)
sma47 = ta.sma(close, 47)

// Check if the 8-period EMA is crossing the 47-period SMA
cross = crossover(ema8, sma47)

// Take a long position if the 8-period EMA is crossing above the 47-period SMA
if (cross and cross[1] == false)
    strategy.entry("Long", 1, stop=strategy.position_avg_price - 1)
    strategy.exit("Long", 1, from_entry=true, take_profit=strategy.position_avg_price + 3)

// Take a short position if the 8-period EMA is crossing below the 47-period SMA
if (cross and cross[1] == true)
    strategy.entry("Short", 1, stop=strategy.position_avg_price + 1)
    strategy.exit("Short", 1, from_entry=true, take_profit=strategy.position_avg_price - 3)
```

`

I need help to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Functions are now in different namespaces in `v5`. The `crossover()` function has been moved to the`ta.` namespace.

So, it should be:

```
cross = ta.crossover(ema8, sma47)
```